# Regarding create VHD

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Recently i bought a external hardisk ( Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex Desk External Drive 3TB,USB3.0) for creating .VHD via hyper-v under windows 2008 R2.
But it is fail! After finding some info, the reason is .VHD under windows 08 r2 only support Bytes Per Sector 512, but the Bytes Per Sector for my external hard disk is 4096.
How to resolve it if i want to create the .VHD in this external hard disk.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Start reading some books how computers work.

- VHD are files. The disc does not care about how the file organizes itself.
- While the VHD internally simulates a disc with a 4096 sector size, it actually always reads or writes megabyte big sectors not to have tons of IO.

But generally, the vhd is a file and doesn't care what sector size your disc uses. Format the disc (sensibly - like always for 10 years for large setups a 64kb node size in NTFS is  better than the default) and just use the wizard to create the VHD file.

Comment: Hi, when create or attach the .vhd it will come out the error mesg:"the sector of the physical disk on which the virtual disk resides is not support". Thanks.

Comment: Did it ever occur to you to enter this exact error message into google? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverhyperv/thread/b47ea3f6-7d52-4dc5-b660-d58ad38d73e1 has a solution. Jsu copy paste teh string into google and mark it with " on both ends, then you will find that it is quite a good search term.

Comment: Also make sure you are fully patched up. THere we re various fixes published in janaury for that.